# Survival model for two survival times

Tags: survival, biostatistics, bivariate

I have two time to event data measured on same individual.they time to diagnose and time to first treatment from diagnosis . i have fitted two cox models separately for two survival times. Now I want to fit a single model to them. Is there any way to do that?
can I go with frailty models?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use the frailty.
Also, there are avrious of method for ordered multiple events such as Anderson Gill, WLW and PWP. you could fit any method of them in R as well.